# How do I OWN a text input with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What's the best way to "own" a text input with jQuery so that I can type into it, listen for events from the point in code that the "owning" happens, but otherwise prevent any other JavaScript from receiving the `keydown` and `keyup` events.

Comment: stop it's events from propagating.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation

Comment: and stop immediate propagation

Comment: Hmmm, so this (http://jsfiddle.net/FJjLD/1/) works but not in my actual project, guess that'll have to be a new question :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop the events from [propogating](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

> We can use event.isPropagationStopped() to determine if this method
>   was ever called (on that event object).
>
> This method works for custom events triggered with trigger(), as well.
>
> Note that this will not prevent other handlers on the same element
>   from running.

Answer (score 0):

Set an event handler on the element directly and use `stopImmediatePropagation()` so even other handlers on the element aren't run. You may also want to `preventDefault()` for some element types.

Make sure your event handler is directly on the element and not using the delegated/live forms, or other handlers can be triggered before the event bubbles up to your handler.

If the element is on the page before your script runs, something else may have already had the chance to add an event handler. In that case, you could go so far as to remove any event handlers already on the element before adding your own. You can fetch an object of event handlers using  `$._data(*element*,"events")` and then increment over the keys to find all the names of the events and remove any event handlers on the object.